# Using @track with @wire causing issues with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, track

I am trying to create a custom list view and deploy a LWC that lists records in the list. My component works with dummy data, but once I created an Apex class to execute my SOQL query it is having issues.

I know my Apex class works fine since I tried it without filtering functionality.

However, to add filtering functionality I am also using `@track`. So that I can track the value of the current items to display based on which filter is active.

I am suspecting that my usages of `@wire` and `@track` are problematic.

When I call `@track` on my dummy, local list inside the JS file, there is no issue (no use of `@wire` at all). When I try to track `applications` that is a result of the `@wire`, the component refuses to load.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
@track itemsForCurrentView = applications;
```

The value will only be assigned once, so it won't be reactive.

```
@wire(getLoanApplications) applications;
```

You need to pass in the filter properties, if any, and make them reactive:

```
@wire(getLoanApplications, { filter: '$currentFilter' }) 
applications;
```

If you need to do any post-processing, do it with a handler:

```
@wire(getLoanApplications, { filter: '$currentFilter' }) 
applicationsWireHandler({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    // You can massage the data if you need to //
    this.itemsForCurrentView = data;
  }
  if(error) {
    // display an error // 
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "pass in filter properties, and make them reactive" would I do `@track itemsForCurrentView = applications`? Or does your code snippet already make it reactive? When I try assigning applications to the @wire with the filter, I get an error saying `applications` is not defined.

Comment: @Lia No, you do not do the assignment; that's only for assigning a default value. `@wire` variables automatically cause update renders, so you do not need to `@track` them manually or assign them elsewhere.

Comment: Then how do I initialize itemsForCurrentView?

Comment: Is there elsewhere where I need to initialize `applications`? I keep getting an error saying it is not defined.

Comment: So it looks like whenever I try to set `itemsForCurrentView` to `applications` it thinks applications is not defined. How else can I set default `itemsForCurrentView` as the applications?

Comment: @Lia Have you looked at [@wire](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)? It explains how it works, with examples. To initialize itemsForCurrentView, use `@track itemsForCurrentView = [];`, then use the `applicationsWireHandler` from my answer to assign the data at that point. This is one of the two standard ways to use it. Or, you can access `this.applications` at any point after its loaded (check `this.applications.data` and `this.applications.error`).

Comment: Yes! I seem to have trouble understanding how to implement with mine. I already have a method called `handleFilterData` that updates `this.itemsForCurrentView` to `this.applications`, so I want to try the latter. However, no data shows up when I try to assign `applications` to the `@wire`.

Comment: If I can use `applicationsWireHandler` as well, then when variable should I use to reference the result of the handler? For example, I'm trying to do `this.itemsForCurrentView = this.applications` when the filter is "ALL". But the wire handler doesn't assign a variable `applications`.

Comment: @Lia In your wire handler, you'd:  `this.applications = data; this.handleFilterData();`

Comment: Thank you! I think there is something wrong with my handleFilterData method. I know where to try to debug now, thank you so much for your help!